# Python global variable is None in another module

Tags: python, global-variables

I have this problem with global variables. After I explicitly assigned some value to a global variable in one module, I tried to access this global variable in a function from another module. It contains None even it already has a value assigned to it. Here's my code below that demonstrates my point:

a.py (main file)

```
import b

fname = None

def get_file(fn):
    try:
        global fname
        fname = fn
        f = open(fn)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        import sys
        sys.exit(1)
    finally:
        return f

def fun(f):
    x = b.Foo(f)
    assert fname is not None
    x.do_shit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fn = "FILE"
    f = get_file(fn)
    fun(f)
    f.close()
```

b.py

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, thing):
        self.thing = thing

    def do_shit(self):
        import a
        assert a.fname is not None
```

Note: Before you run a.py, make a file named "FILE" first (no extension)

When I run a.py, I get this following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 24, in <module>
    fun(f)
  File "a.py", line 19, in fun
    x.do_shit()
  File "F:\Peep\b.py", line 7, in do_shit
    assert a.fname is not None
AssertionError
```

Can anybody explain why the global variable from another module is None and how can I fix this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do not reimport the module you have started. If you do, you will have two versions in memory: one as `__main__` and one as `a`.

Comment: In general, using global variables is quite a bad practice, so I would try different approaches. In any case, when you run b.py, the `__main__` section of a.py will never be run, since that section is ignored when the module is imported